# JavaFX 11.0.2 not working on Intellij (java 11)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I've been browsing Stack overflow and googling my way through this for the past 3 hours, and nothing seems to be helping.

My Project Structure settings are as follows:

```
Project SDK: "11 (java version "11.0.2")
```

`Project language level: "11 - Local variable syntax for lambda parameters"` - I have also tried the SDK default

Under Modules I have imported all javafx-sdk-11.0.2 jar files

And my VM options:

```
--module-path C:\Program Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Now, whenever I try to run an Application, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
```

**EDIT:**

I added the path into quotation marks, that in turn moved on to the next error:
"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found"

Comment: quote your module-path - `--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"`

Comment: Now I get "java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found"

Comment: Probably ought to try adding that one to your `--add-modules` list. The first error was caused by the space in your module-path.

Comment: It remains the same, once added to --add-modules. Also I can see that file in my javafx sdk folder.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I got it fixed by using the following VM options:
--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base

And I also tried adding individual jar files to my modules, which seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

With IJ,
Click Run
Choose Edit Configurations
In the VM Options Enter
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Or
--module-path "here insert your path" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

Apparently I was using JavaFX 11.0.2 with a JDK that was in /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home which showed up in the Project Settings as 11.0.6. I switched to Adopt OpenJDK 11 and the problem was resolved.